# IBM DB2 and PL/SQL compatibility

Tags: oracle, db2

I know it's a very dumb question to ask but can somebody please let me know if DB2 supports PL/SQL as programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a dumb question at all, and DB2 for LUW supports the majority of PL/SQL features since version 9.7, adding more compatibility with each new version. PL/SQL in DB2 is compiled into the same bytecode as the native DB2 SQL PL, so there is no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 for LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows) does now support PL/SQL. Alas, the other DB2, DB2 for i, and apparently DB2 for z/OS, do not currently support PL/SQL syntax.

Comment: Personally, I just use IBM's Information Centers as my primary source, along with articles I find from them and other sources.  But I'm a DB2 for i DBA so I'm not your best source for LUW information.  Perhaps someone else will make a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I am finding it difficult to learn DB2 sql as there are very few resource in web. :(